# Joining duplicates rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Suppose I have a dataframe like this one:

```
                Date    Issuer Ticker  Duplicate Value
0  05/14/20 00:00:00  BARCLAYS     SQ          0   NaN
1  05/11/20 00:00:00  BARCLAYS     SQ          0     1
2  05/11/20 00:00:00     ARGUS    TTD          0   NaN
3  05/11/20 00:00:00     ARGUS    TTD          0     1
4  05/11/20 00:00:00  BARCLAYS     SQ          0   NaN
```

And I want to give 'Duplicate' a value of '1' whenever there's an event happening twice in the same date, such as: 05/11/20 BARCLAYS SQ (occuring twice) and join the two rows so that if 'Value' exists it overrides NaNs in the other row.

I'll be very thankful of some help guys!

THX!!!

edit:
expected output after joining:

```
                Date    Issuer Ticker  Duplicate Value
0  05/14/20 00:00:00  BARCLAYS     SQ          0   NaN
1  05/11/20 00:00:00  BARCLAYS     SQ          0     1
3  05/11/20 00:00:00     ARGUS    TTD          0     1
```

Comment: Can you ad expected output? What is exected output if Value are `NaN, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need remove rows with missing values only for duplicated rows by 3 columns names use:

```
mask1 = df.duplicated(['Date','Issuer','Ticker'], keep=False)
mask2 = df['Value'].notna()

df = df[~mask1 | mask2]
print (df)
                Date    Issuer Ticker  Duplicate  Value
0  05/14/20 00:00:00  BARCLAYS     SQ          0    NaN
1  05/11/20 00:00:00  BARCLAYS     SQ          0    1.0
3  05/11/20 00:00:00     ARGUS    TTD          0    1.0
```

Comment: I think op wants to join the rows that have same `Date` and `Ticker`  and then update the `Duplicated` value to 1

Comment: @komatiraju032 - thank you, I checked question and then edited answer.

Comment: hi thanks very much for the help, is there a way ot join the 2 SQ's and 2 TTD's who have duplicate=1 with each other and keep the value that exists?

Comment: @jezrael hi yes please check my edit on the original post, ive added the expected output after joining, the idea is to basically combine the rows and if there's any value missing in one of the rows but exists in the other to combine them (an OR operation going over each column)

Comment: this works good but when I'm trying to add another column to mask2 like this: `mask2 = df['Value1', 'Value2'].notna()` then I am getting an error when I'm trying to set ~mask1, mask2 to df, is there a way of doing the same thing and joining in more columns as values?

Comment: @orie - Then use `mask2 = df[['Value1', 'Value2']].notna().all(axis=1)`